# Issue with org.junit.*; in Netbeans "package org.junit does not exist"

Tags: java, netbeans, junit

I am attempting to make a to do list and need to import org.junit. However, NetBeans will not acknowledge that this package exists. I get the error:"package org.junit does not exist". I tested importing org.xml.sax.Attributes, which worked. 
I'm using NetBeans 8.2 on windows 10 Version 10.0.15063 Build 15063

What I have attempted:

- adding JUnit through "Add Library"
- clearing the cache
- restarting NetBeans
- restarting my PC

What else can I do in order to get Junit to work

Comment: Did you add the library to the correct module? If so, did you add junit to the module's _Test libraries_ or _Libraries_? If it's added to _Test Libraries_, you can only access it from classes in _Test Packages_.

Answer (score 3):

Add Library JUnit 4.x to folder "Test Libraries"

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this same issue using **Netbeans 8.2**. The issue seems to occur for me because I added already coded **JUnit classes** to my project.

To resolve the issue, I imported **JUnit** and **Hamcrest** by right clicking on my project. Then going to Project **Properties -> Libraries -> Compile Tests -> Add Library** and then the same for **Run Tests**.

Next, I added a new **JUnit class** to the test package. Once this was added Netbeans acknowledged that I had added **JUnit**.

Answer (score 0):

The above solutions did not give me the solution. BUT I came up with a simple idea which works out for me, That is
 LIBRARIES->RIGHT CLICK - >ADD LIBRARY - > select JUNIT
-> click ADD LIBRARY. well i think this will solve your problem..

Comment: Hi Silva, welcome to the forum. Is this different than the "adding JUnit through "Add Library" "  that the author says has alrady tried?

Answer (score 0):

i right clicked 'libraries' and then clicked 'add JAR/folder' and pointed to these JAR files which i first downloaded and saved https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api

Answer (score 0):

The archives of mathemagician have resolve the problem. Installing the junit 5 jar in a folder junit_5 in libraries